# Azure Table Storage partition limit

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

What is the limit on the number of partitions that can belong to an Azure table?

The only decent source of information regarding table storage limitations I have found are [here (2012)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx) and [here(2010)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.aspx).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no limit. As your links suggest, there are mostly scalability targets and limitations on the physical keys and entities that describe the table schema.

Comment: I've asked the same Q to MSFT and received this response.